# Mac OS word delimiter character settings

Tags: macos, keyboard, system-settings

I seem to remember seeing a tip once where there was a setting in System Preferences where you can define "programming" as a language or something so that double-clicking on a hyphenated word selects the entire word, hyphen and all.

I did this on my older MBP and now can't remember how to do it for my new one (10.9.1)

Comment: what do you mean by define "programming" as a language or something

Comment: there was a way to set in as a variant of English.  Unless I'm hallucinating...

Comment: The only thing I can see that sounds like that is the Format language in language & region's Advance section

Answer (score 1):

There's a setting that might be what you're referring to:

OS X Preferences > Language & Region > Region > Americas > **United States (Computer)**

Comment: We are looking for more than a short answer.  Consider adding some supporting references to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alas the 'Computer' language has been foolishly removed from the choices in macOS.
That ':' is considered part of a word astounds me.